# Nodejs: Passing function specific variables to Async.parallel()

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am have a bunch of long running database queries I need to get done before I render a page in node. Each of these queries require a few of their own variables. Is there an easy way to pass variables to the async.parallel() utility in nodejs?

```
async.parallel([
    queryX(callback, A1, A2, A3),
    queryX(callback, B1, B2, B3),
    queryY(callback, C1, C2, C3),
    queryY(callback, D1, D2, D3),
    queryZ(callback, E1, E2, E3),
    queryZ(callback, F1, F2, F3),
  ], 
  function(err, results) { /*Do Render Stuff with Results*/}
);
```

Comment: No, `async` does not have helpers for this. You could try `.bind()` or similar partial application methods, but your callback being in the first place is odd and might hinder using them.

Answer (score 5):

You should respect the callback as last argument nodejs convention when you write functions. That way you could have use Function.bind to call your functions instead.

```
var queryx = function(A,B,C,callback){ .... ; callback(err,result) };

async.parallel([queryx.bind(null,A1,B2,A3),...,],callback);
```

bind returns a partial application :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an easy way to pass variables to the async.parallel() utility in nodejs?

Not in `async` itself, you could however write a little helper function for this:

```
function passWithCallbackFirst(fn) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return function(cb) {
        args.unshift(cb);
        return fn.apply(this, args);
    };
}

async.parallel([
    passWithCallbackFirst(queryX, A1, A2, A3),
    passWithCallbackFirst(queryX, B1, B2, B3),
    passWithCallbackFirst(queryY, C1, C2, C3),
    passWithCallbackFirst(queryY, D1, D2, D3),
    passWithCallbackFirst(queryZ, E1, E2, E3),
    passWithCallbackFirst(queryZ, F1, F2, F3),
], function(err, results) {
    /*Do Render Stuff with Results*/
});
```